# PHP IDE: How is that functionality called

Tags: php, php-ide

please how is called the functionality in IDEs when your cursor is on some of your method and you press (for example) Ctrl + MOUSE CLICK and you will be moved to the method’s source code (i know for sure that PhpEd has it).. I am looking for some PHP IDE for MAC with this feature and i found nothing :// I tried Aptana, NetBeans but this feature is missing .

Comment: I think you're looking for the function/method definition? [PHP Storm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/features/index.html#PHPDoc_support) seems to support that. You have to have the definition files available (PHPDoc, for instance).

Comment: The problem with this feature for PHP is that PHP is a loosely typed language. That is, if there's a variable named $myvar then most IDEs will not have a clue if this is a string, an int, an object (and of which class), a resource, or whatever.. Which makes it even harder for the IDE to know which function you mean when you Ctrl+Click on $myvar->someFunction.

Comment: this feature works in NetBeans for Linux.

Comment: I'm not a Mac person, but the context menu in Aptana does offer `Open Declaration` and `Open Definition` on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

It may be called `Go to definition/declaration`